# Highcharts pie donut with gradient

Tags: javascript, svg, highcharts, gradient

Is there a way using Highcharts, to achieve that kind of gradients?

[image]

Here is some [jsfiddle boilerplate](http://jsfiddle.net/vGNBc/2/)

```
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart: {
        renderTo: 'chart',
        type: 'pie'
    },
    exporting: { 
        enabled: false
    },
    credits: {
        enabled: false
    },
    title: {
        text: null
    },
    tooltip: {
        enabled: false
    },
    plotOptions: {
        pie: {
            animation: false,
            enableMouseTracking: false,
            borderColor: 'transparent',
            colors: ['#fdc81c', '#eee'],
            borderWidth: 0,
            innerSize: '60%',
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: false
            }
        }
    },
    series: [{ data: [80, 20] }]
})
```

Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately only linear and radial gradients are supported by Highcharts (if you want to use them replace the colors by an object as described here: http://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-design-and-style/colors). What you need is a conical gradient which is currently not supported.

Answer (score 2):

you can use radial gradient for highcharts, but I'm afraid you would not get the filling of color as per the value.

highcharts have provided in their documentation [here](http://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-design-and-style/colors) that radial and linear gradients can be used with highcharts.

Comment: Indeed, gradients are supported. But only these gradient which are supported by SVG.

Answer (score 0):

Highcharts only have two types of gradients, linear and radial, so you cannot solve your problem using them. That is why I start thinking how to do it and after wasting a lot of time, I decided to implement it by dividing the chart in small **slices** with different colors.
Then I have a donut/pie chart with 100 little slices and each one has a different color.

[Gradient color degraded from 0 to 100%](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KUFru.png)
[Gradient color degraded from 0 to 60%](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XjyLZ.png)
I am developing a react-native application, so I post you the code here:

**gradientColors.js**

```
export default ['#41E500','#44E500','#47E500','#4AE500','#4DE600','#50E601','#53E601','#56E601','#59E701','#5CE702','#5FE702','#62E702','#65E802','#68E803','#6BE803','#6EE903','#71E903','#74E904','#77E904','#7AEA04','#7DEA04','#80EA05','#83EA05','#86EB05','#89EB05','#8CEB05','#8FEC06','#92EC06','#95EC06','#98EC06','#9BED07','#9EED07','#A1ED07','#A4ED07','#A7EE08','#AAEE08','#ADEE08','#B0EE08','#B3EF09','#B6EF09','#B9EF09','#BCF009','#BFF00A','#C2F00A','#C5F00A','#C8F10A','#CBF10A','#CEF10B','#D1F10B','#D4F20B','#D7F20B','#DAF20C','#DDF30C','#E0F30C','#E3F30C','#E6F30D','#E9F40D','#ECF40D','#EFF40D','#F2F40E','#F5F50E','#F8F50E','#FBF50E','#FFF60F','#FFF60F','#FFF20E','#FFEF0E','#FFEC0D','#FFE80D','#FFE50C','#FFE20C','#FFDE0C','#FFDB0B','#FFD80B','#FFD50A','#FFD10A','#FFCE0A','#FFCB09','#FFC709','#FFC408','#FFC108','#FFBE07','#FFBA07','#FFB707','#FFB406','#FFB006','#FFAD05','#FFAA05','#FFA705','#FFA705','#FF9805','#FF8906','#FF7B06','#FF6C07','#FF5D07','#FF4F08','#FF4008','#FF3109','#FF230A','#FF230A'];
```

**ProgressChart.js**

```
'use strict';

const Highcharts = 'Highcharts';
import { COLORS } from '@theme';
import gradientColors from './gradientColors';

const fakeData = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1];

const data = [{
  y: 100,
  color: COLORS.dark_red,
  drilldown: {
    name: 'Categories',
    categories: ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'],
    data: fakeData,
    color: COLORS.dark_red
  }
}];
const donutData = [];
const donutDataOuter = [];

const dataLen = data.length;
// Build the data arrays
for (let i = 0; i < dataLen; i += 1) {

  // add data
  const drillDataLen = data[i].drilldown.data.length;
  for (let j = 0; j < drillDataLen; j += 1) {

    if (j > 60) {
      donutData.push({
        y: data[i].drilldown.data[j],
        color: 'white',
        borderColor: 'white'
      });
      donutDataOuter.push({
        y: data[i].drilldown.data[j],
        color: 'white',
        borderColor: 'white'
      });
    } else {
      donutData.push({
        y: data[i].drilldown.data[j],
        color: gradientColors[j],
        borderColor: gradientColors[j]
      });
      donutDataOuter.push({
        y: data[i].drilldown.data[j],
        color: gradientColors[j],
        borderColor: gradientColors[j]
      });
    }
  }
}

const donutConf = {
  chart: {
    type: 'pie',
    animation: Highcharts.svg
  },
  title: {
    text: 'Equipment types (%)',
    align: 'center',
    verticalAlign: 'middle',
    floating: true,
    style: {
      color: COLORS.light_grey_2,
      fontWeight: 'bold',
      fontSize: 38
    }
  },
  plotOptions: {
    pie: {
      shadow: false,
      center: ['50%', '50%']
    },
    showCheckbox: true
  },
  tooltip: {
    formatter() {
      return '<b>' + this.series.name + '</b><br/>' +
        Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y, 2) + ' %';
    }
  },
  legend: {
    enabled: true
  },
  exporting: {
    enabled: false
  },
  series: [
    {
      name: 'Categories',
      data: donutData,
      size: '93%',
      innerSize: '58%',
      dataLabels: {
        enabled: false
      },
      id: 'inner'
    },
    {
      name: 'Categories2',
      data: donutDataOuter,
      size: '100%',
      innerSize: '97%',
      dataLabels: {
        enabled: false
      },
      id: 'outer'
    }],
};

export default donutConf;
```

I have developed it very fast. So the example code above is for the 60% chart. In my final version I won't include this dirty if-else clauses I will solve it

Then in your case I recommend you to use this webpage http://www.perbang.dk/rgbgradient/ and use the number of steps that you need. For instance you can simply chose 2 from green to blue as I show you [in this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i0yel.png). After copying the hex codes to the gradientColors variable you will be able to solve your problem.