# How to create a solid guage gradient in Highcharts

Tags: highcharts, gradient

I am trying to create a I want to style my chart with gradient color from success to error like this:

[image]

Here's what I have so far:

```
series: [
        {
          type: "solidgauge",
          name: `${legendText}: ${data}%`,
          color: renderLevelInfo.color,
          data: [
            {
              radius: "100%",
              innerRadius: "85%",
              y: data,
              color: {
                linearGradient: {
                  x1: 0.5,
                  x2: 0.2,
                  y1: 0,
                  y2: 0,
                },
                stops: [
                  [0, theme.colors.success],
                  [0.5, theme.colors.success],
                  [0.7, theme.colors.warning],
                  [0.99, theme.colors.error],
                ],
              },
            },
          ],
        },
      ],
```

### Research Effort

- [Gauge - possible to do gradient for fill?](https://www.highcharts.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=35174)
- [Highcharts solidgauge with green/yellow/red gradient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36240478/highcharts-solidgauge-with-green-yellow-red-gradient)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Highcharts pie donut with gradient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22367109/highcharts-pie-donut-with-gradient)